# Unable to mount CIFS on Raspberry Pi, because CIFS is not listed in /proc/filesystem (and its module can't be found)

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian, cifs

I'm trying to mount some CIFS shares on my raspberry pi. I've done it before but now I'm stuck at this:

```
pi@raspberrypi-server:~ $ sudo mount -a
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
mount error(19): No such device
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

after some research, I noticed CIFS is not listed in filesystems:

```
pi@raspberrypi-server:~ $ cat /proc/filesystems
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   ramfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   cpuset
nodev   cgroup
nodev   cgroup2
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   devtmpfs
nodev   configfs
nodev   debugfs
nodev   tracefs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   pipefs
nodev   rpc_pipefs
nodev   devpts
        ext3
        ext2
        ext4
        vfat
        msdos
nodev   nfs
nodev   nfs4
nodev   autofs
        f2fs
nodev   mqueue
        fuseblk
nodev   fuse
nodev   fusectl
```

kept trying, I found somewhere a suggestion to:

```
pi@raspberrypi-server:~ $ modprobe cifs
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.14.79-v7+/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module cifs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.79-v7+
```

what leads me to believe this modprobe is pointing out to the wrong module package, since I can't find a 4.14.79-v7+ folder, but instead:

```
pi@raspberrypi-server:~ $ ls /lib/modules/
4.14.98+  4.14.98-v7+
```

I think it should point out to one of those 4.14.98 folders. (I've already browsed them.. they do have a CIFS module).
That's it.. I have too little linux knowledge to find out a way to enable CIFS.

** UPDATE **
modprobe is pointing to that folder, because my uname points to it. I wonder how to work this out.

```
pi@raspberrypi-server:~ $ uname -r
4.14.79-v7+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=63838

Comment: no. It's not an "Operation not supported" error. In that case CIFS is supported.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question. Perhaps try [raspberrypi.se]?

Answer (score 1):

@Tiago, I had the same issue immediately after dist-upgrade. Reboot fixed this.

Comment: Yep.. I agree it's related.. booting was not enough for me.. I ended up reflashing the image and doing it prior to upgrading my packages. Now it's fine. Something must have gone wrong in dist-upgrade. The second attempt, in the new image, everything turned out fine.